# e not equal to exp in Maple 2019.1

Tags: maple

Can anyone explain why Maple 2019.1 does not recognize that e and exp are equivalent?

[image]

Comment: The problem could perhaps be explained by this Top 10 Maple Errors  https://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m210/topten.pdf, since exp(x) is the proper exponential function whereas e^x is just a letter e.  However -- this does not explain why none of the quantities:  simplify(ln(e^x)) nor simplify(ln(exp(x))) nor simplify(log(e^x)) nor simplify(log(exp(x)) will simplify... all four of them give result displayed as ln(e^x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your original question is that `e` is just a letter in 1D plaintext Maple notation, and doesn't mean anything. In particular it is not related to the base of the natural logarithm, and it is not equal to `exp(1)`. They are not equivalent syntax.

As for your followup comment, `ln(exp(x))` is not equal to `x` for all complex values of `x`, which is why Maple does not simplify the former to the latter. In this context Maple will consider an unknown name such as `x` to be complex-valued, and possibly nonreal.

Look at the help page for topic `ln`, which explains in the second paragraph of its description,

```
For complex-valued expressions x, 
          ln(x) = ln(abs(x)) + argument(x)*I
where
          -Pi <argument(x) <= Pi
Throughout Maple, this computation is taken to be the
definition of the principal branch of the logarithm.
```

Perhaps you were thinking of purely real `x`? If so then you have to inform Maple of that special aspect -- it doesn't read your mind.

```
simplify(ln(exp(x))) assuming x::real;
                           x
```

Some more examples,

```
simplify(ln(exp(A+B*I))) assuming A::real,B::real,B>0,B<Pi;

                        A + I B

simplify(ln(exp(1+3/2*Pi*I)));

                           1     
                       1 - - I Pi
                           2     

simplify(evalc(ln(exp(A+B*I))));

              A + I arctan(sin(B), cos(B))
```

And, plotting part of that last expression,

```
plot( arctan(sin(B), cos(B)),
      B = -3.5*Pi..3.5*Pi,
      xtickmarks=piticks );
```

[image]